# Why does the Fermi energy enter in this equation?

Tags: solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

I am studying the book *Solid state physics* by Ashcroft & Merrin; in particular I am studying chapter 18: *Surface effects*.

In this chapter, authors say that to remove an electron from the surface, one has to give the energy $$E=-E_F+W$$ where $E_F$ is the (negative of the) Fermi energy and $W$ is the work function.

What I do not understand is: Why does the Fermi energy come into the equation for all the electrons?

I would have said that for the electrons in the highest energy levels one should provide only an energy equal to the work function.

Comment: Are you looking at equation 18.8 or 18.9?

Comment: @JonCuster 18.9

Comment: OK, in my edition it is typeset differently as $W = -\epsilon_{F} + W_{s}$ with $W$ the work function of interest, $\epsilon_{F}$ the Fermi energy (in the bulk relative to infinity and hence negative) and $W_{s}$ is the work to overcome the surface potential ('double layer').

Comment: So, without surface effects, the work function would just be the amount of energy to take an electron from the Fermi energy to infinity, or just the negative of the Fermi energy (measured relative to infinity). But, surface effects add more on.

Comment: @JonCuster The authors write that the formula 18.8 works for electrons ***from the interior*** of the crystal: does the 18.9 works only in this case too? Which is the energy required to remove an electron ***from the surface*** of the crystal?

Comment: The whole point of 18.9 is to modify the relationship to account for the surface energy term. An electron from the interior has to pass through the surface. An electron on the surface still has to escape the surface.

Comment: @JonCuster but to remove the electron from the surface is ***only*** $W$ (without $E_F$) enough?

Comment: No - reread the page or so and look at the figures that show what the different components represent.